# Kerberos Authentication - AWS RDS - Error ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-rds

We are trying to authenticate MYSQL users with AD.
We have followed all the required steps as mentioned in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-kerberos.html.
We are able to create a user with

```
    CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'auth_pam';
    UPDATE mysql.user SET ssl_type = 'any' WHERE ssl_type = '' AND PLUGIN = 'auth_pam' and USER = 'testuser';`
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However when we are trying to connect to this RDS MYSQL instance with AD password getting below error :

```
    ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/dialog.so, 2): image not found
```

Steps we have tried at client side :

Changing

```
    default_authentication_plugin => mysql_native_password
    
    trying to connect with 
    --enable-cleartext-plugin
```

On Destination server

```
    SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
           WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE '%pam%';
    query is giving result : 
    
    auth_pam => ACTIVE
```

AD and server are in the same VPC there are no connectivity issues.
Please suggest if anyone encountered this with MYSQL and AD integration.